# MySQL, PHP - Forms Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

This is a little part of a college website project I have and I've ran into this issue. 
I hope you can help me with it.
I've made a small representation of this issue so it's easier to read.

What I'm trying to do here is:

- doubt1.php = shows a form.

  doubt2.php = shows form with the values from doubt1.php for confirmation.

  doubt3.php = saves values to database.

  class.php = library of clases(only name).

**The problem is that it saves empty values at doubt3.php.**

If I skip doubt2.php and redirect the form from doubt1.php to doubt3.php I have no problem at all, it saves successfully.

These are the codes:

**doubt1.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name=f action=doubt2.php method=post>
        <input name=name value="Hello";>
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**doubt2.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php

        $y=$_REQUEST['name'];
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form name=f action=doubt3.php method=post>
        <input name=name value="<?php echo $y; ?>" disabled>
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**doubt3.php**

```
<?php

    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("doubtdb");

    if(!mysql_select_db("doubtdb")){
        $q1="create database doubtdb";
        $q2="use doubtdb";
        $q3="create table data(name varchar(10))";

        mysql_query($q1,$c);
        mysql_query($q2,$c);
        mysql_query($q3,$c);

        mysql_select_db('doubtdb');
    }

    include "class.php";

    $obj=new data($_REQUEST['name']);
    $obj->save($c);

    echo "Saved";
?>
```

**class.php**

```
<?php

    class data{

        private $name;

        function __construct($name){
            $this->name=$name;
        }

        function set_name($name){
            $this->name=$name;
        }

        function get_name(){
            return $this->name;
        }

        function save($c){

            $q="insert into data values('$this->name')";

            mysql_query($q,$c);
            mysql_close($c);
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

disabled input is not submited with the form.
try "readonly"

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem.
I should have used readonly instead of disabled.

Comment: Hi. new user welcome to stackoverflow one point in this site is supporting. one supports you with answer. And you would support him/her with accepting and/or voting the answers up/down. (-: